# keras lstm model error and loss remain the same through fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, forecasting

I have a model but the fitting process isn't making it any better.  Error stays the same throughout the process and all predictions are 1.0.

Trying to get a model to predict the next value in a time series, value is a weekly sales and is 107 long

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1, 50)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 64))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['mae'])

model.fit(x = train_x, y = train_y, batch_size = 23, epochs = 100)

Epoch 1/100
36/36 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.6570 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8036     
Epoch 2/100
36/36 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6570 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8036
```

....

```
Epoch 99/100
36/36 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6570 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8036     
Epoch 100/100
36/36 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6570 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8036  

model.predict(x = test_x)

array([[1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

help me SO, you're my only hope

Comment: Based on the final dense layer, given that you're using softmax, wouldn't you want to use the `categorical_crossentropy` for your loss function? (or `binary_crossentropy `)

Comment: you're absolutely right, but i'm trying to do regression so i should never have used softmax to begin with. took off the softmax activation and it does look like it fixed the issue.  Now, my loss goes down to 5.6e-4 but my accuracy stays at .0278.

this means my model is only 2.7% accurate during the training phase right? 

if you want to answer in an actual answer, i'll check it off as you having answered my questions. thanks for the help :)

Comment: That's ok, as long as it solved your issue! Now hopefully you figure out how to get accuracy to improve :)